Why does extension.json not find the .js and .css resources indicated in ResourceModule?
I'm writing a very simple extension to Mediawiki to use the able player plugin to create playlists on my wiki pages.
Although the path are correct in the mandatory extension.json (I verified using the URLs with a browser) and the directory (755) and file (644) permissions are correct, the files lib/ext.Playlist.js and lib/ext.Playlist.css are not loaded.
I do not see them in the browser console.
This is an extract from my extension.json file:
"AutoloadClasses": {
                "PlaylistHooks": "includes/PlaylistHooks.php"
        },
        "ResourceModules": {
                "ext.Playlist": {
                        "scripts": [
                                "lib/ext.Playlist.js"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                                "lib/ext.Playlist.css"
                        ]
                }
        },
        "ResourceFileModulePaths": {
                "localBasePath": "",
                "remoteExtPath": "Playlist"
        },
        "Hooks": {
                "ParserFirstCallInit": "PlaylistHooks::onParserFirstCallInit"
        },
        "manifest_version": 2

Conversely, the file includes/PlaylistHooks.php is loaded correctly.
This is the directory structure
/var/www/w/MtWiki/
└── extensions/
    └── Playlist/
        ├── includes/
        │   └── PlaylistHooks.php
        ├── lib/
        │   ├── ext.Playlist.js
        │   └── ext.Playlist.css
        ├── ableplayer/
        │   ├── ableplayer.min.js
        │   └── ableplayer.min.css
        ├── extension.json
        └── Playlist.php

Ii tried to put this in my LocalSettings.php configuration file
$wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] = function ( $out, $skin ) {
    $out->addScriptFile( '/extensions/Playlist/lib/ext.Playlist.js' );
    $out->addStyle( '/extensions/Playlist/lib/ext.Playlist.css' );
    return true;
};

but I got a 404 not found error in console:
Summary
URL: https://ttadev.org/extensions/Playlist/lib/ext.Playlist.js
Status: 404 Not Found
Source: Network
Initiator: 
Sandbox:232

Request
Accept: */*
Referer: https://ttadev.org/wiki/Sandbox
Sec-Fetch-Dest: script
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.5 Safari/605.1.15


What directory is set as the document root? Even https://ttadev.org/extensions/ is giving a 404

The root is https://ttadev.org/w/ (or /var/www/w/).

When using resource loader, you should not load the extensions from the browser-side using the direct url. Instead, you should load them with something like https://ttadev.org/w/load.php?modules=ext.Playlist. If you use the addModules method on OutputPage in the BeforePageDisplay hook, this module will be loaded automatically on the pages you specified in that hook. See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Developing_with_ResourceLoader#Loading%20modules for some more info
